# Jenkinsfile checkout to a specific folder via git command

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run this command in the jenkinsfile

```
git checkout <repo> <folder name>
```

but I get this error

```
[git-checkout-example] Running shell script
+ git checkout git@code.in.spdigital.io:sp-digital/jarvis-api.git wahahah
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Any idea how can I go about doing it in Jenkinsfile? can I checkout the files to a specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

> can I checkout the files to a specific folder?

You can checkout files *of* a specific folder, not *to a specific folder.

See [`git checkout` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

> When `<paths>` is given, `git checkout` does not switch branches.
>   It updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file or from a named `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit).
>
> `git checkout` with `<paths>` is used to restore modified or deleted paths to their original contents from the index or replace paths with the contents from a named `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit-ish).

But in your case, the issue comes from your current working directory when you are executing `git checkout xxx -- path`: you need to be in a git repo.

Trying to checkout a repo *to* a path is called [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), not `git checkout`.

Comment: I am talking about using it with conjunction with jenkinsfile

Comment: @MosesLiaoGZ Exactly. Me too. Check your current working directory when you are doing this git command. And make sure a checkout is what you actually want to do. Jenkinsfile or not.